# Ordered broadcast to Service

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, broadcast, intentfilter

I have a use case where a `Service` does some work on the background and needs to notify an event to two `Activities` and one `Service`. I am using a ordered broadcast because:

1) If `ActivityA` is on the foreground, it handles the incoming event and then aborts the broadcast. This way, `ActivityB` and `Service` are not notified.

2) In case the broadcast is not aborted, `ActivityB` is the next on the line. It also cancels the broadcast if active.

3) Otherwise, `Service` deals with the event.

For that, there is a `BroadcastReceiver` on each component with a different priority. The `Service's BroadcastReceiver` is an inner static class and the `<receiver>` is declared in AndroidManifest.xml with the proper `<intent-filter>`.

The problem is, as pointed out [here](http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/04/17/do-not-have-accidental-api.html), I don't want anyone eavesdropping my broadcasts by leaving custom actions on the manifest, but I don't know any other means of achieving ordering other than using an ordered broadcast.

Any other options?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [Android Interface Definition Language](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html) for communication instead.

Comment: I think AIDL is an overkill in this case. Besides, the components reside in the same process.